# Does $\sum_{x/2<p<x}\frac{1}{p}$ tend to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: number-theory, analysis

It is known (Mertens) that $\sum_{p<x}\frac{1}{p}=\log\log x+M+O(\frac{1}{\log x})$. Does starting the summation at $x/2$ ensure the divergence as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: Just plug in $x/2$ to the given asymptote and subtract it from the original.

Comment: In particular, note that $\log \log x/2$ $=\log(\log x-\log 2)$ $=\log (\log x\cdot(1-\frac{\log 2}{\log x}))$... can you continue from here?

Comment: Ok so my sum tends to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sum
  $$ \sum_{x/2<p<x} \frac1p $$
is bounded just because it does not exceed the sum
  $$ \sum_{x/2\le n<x} \frac1n $$
(extended onto *all integers* $x/2\le n<x$), and this latter sum is
  $$ \log(x) - \log(x/2) + O(1) = O(1). $$
Nothing advanced (like Mertens's estimate) is really needed here.